# Why does SQL Server Management Studio hang (Not Responding) when connecting to Amazon RDS?

Tags: ssms, amazon-rds, ssms-2012

When I use SSMS to connect to a database hosted on Amazon RDS, the IDE hangs (as in goes to "Not Responding) after login. I enter SQL Authentication credentials and click Connect and the login window closes as it would for successful authentication. From there I get the "wait" cursor spinning indefinitely and the window status eventually changes to "Not Responding." The only thing I can do from there is force the application to close.

- I have checked logs through Event Viewer and there are no entries for the 5 minutes before or after the error.
- I **have been able to connect** to this database within the past month through SSMS using the same credentials
- I **can connect** to local SQL Server databases with no errors or problems
- I **can connect** to this database now using Visual Studio's IDE using the same credentials
- I **can connect** to this database now through code (e.g. by configuring a connection string and executing a local console or web application)
- SSMS version is 11.0.3128.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [latest SSMS releases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt238290(SQL.130).aspx)? They include improvements to provide better support for SQL Servers running in the cloud. This may help resolve your issue.

Comment: Although this doesn't explain why SSMS 2012 stopped working, it doesn't really matter ... updating the tools is the right thing to do, so I'm accepting this answer!

I've got the latest SSMS version and can connect to Amazon RDS again.